# Android:Null exception while passing intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I have setup a broadcast and I want to handle swap events.Swap events worked fine when I hadn't setup any service,but now there seems to be a null point exception in the intent and hence the swap events are not being handled properly.

the error is in this line:

```
intentswap.putExtra("swap",-1 );
            sendBroadcast(intentswap);
```

The code for my activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.now_playing);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        position = i.getIntExtra("Data2", 0);
        songdetails = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Data1");

        //intentswap=new Intent(BROADCAST_SWAP);
        bfake=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bFake);
        try 
        {   intentplaypause=new Intent(BROADCAST_PLAYPAUSE);
            intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_SEEKBAR);
        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, Music_service.class);
        initViews();
        setListeners();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
        playAudio(position);
        buttonPlayStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        boolMusicPlaying = true;




    }



    private void setListeners() {

        bfake.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener()
         {          
             @Override
             public void onSwipeRight() 
         { z=-1;
         intentswap=new Intent(BROADCAST_SWAP);
         intentswap.putExtra("swap",-1 );
                sendBroadcast(intentswap);
             }
             @Override
             public void onSwipeLeft() {
                    z=1;
                    intentswap=new Intent(BROADCAST_SWAP);
                    intentswap.putExtra("swap",1 );
                        sendBroadcast(intentswap);
                }
               }
                 );
        buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonPlayStopClick();
            }
        });
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    }

    // not working correctly,also i have to add pause and not stop
    private void buttonPlayStopClick() {
        if (!boolMusicPlaying) {
            buttonPlayStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            playAudio(position);
            boolMusicPlaying = true;
        } else {
            if (boolMusicPlaying) {
                buttonPlayStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                stopMusic_service();
                boolMusicPlaying = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void playAudio(int position2) {

        position2 = position;
        serviceIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("sentAudioLink", songdetails);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("postion_service", position);

        try {
            startService(serviceIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                Music_service.BROADCAST_ACTION));
        mBroadcastIsRegistered = true;
    }

    private void stopMusic_service() {

        if (mBroadcastIsRegistered) {
            try {
//              unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    //          mBroadcastIsRegistered = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.e(TAG, "Error in Activity", e);
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(

                getApplicationContext(),

                e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),

                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        try {
            stopService(serviceIntent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        boolMusicPlaying = false;
    }

    private void initViews() {
        buttonPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlayPause);
        buttonPlayStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar sb, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
         if (fromUser) {
             int seekPos = sb.getProgress();
                intent.putExtra("seekpos", seekPos);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
         }
    }

    private void showPD(Intent bufferIntent) {
        String bufferValue = bufferIntent.getStringExtra("buffering");
        int bufferIntValue = Integer.parseInt(bufferValue);

        // When the broadcasted "buffering" value is 1, show "Buffering"
        // progress dialogue.
        // When the broadcasted "buffering" value is 0, dismiss the progress
        // dialogue.

        switch (bufferIntValue) {

        // Listen for "2" to reset the button to a play button
        case 2:
            buttonPlayStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            break;

        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent serviceIntent) {
            updateUI(serviceIntent);
        }
    };

    private void updateUI(Intent serviceIntent) {
        String counter = serviceIntent.getStringExtra("counter");
        String mediamax = serviceIntent.getStringExtra("mediamax");
        String strSongEnded = serviceIntent.getStringExtra("song_ended");
        int seekProgress = Integer.parseInt(counter);
        seekMax = Integer.parseInt(mediamax);
        songEnded = Integer.parseInt(strSongEnded);
        seekbar.setMax(seekMax);
        seekbar.setProgress(seekProgress);
        if (songEnded == 1) {
            buttonPlayStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastBufferReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent bufferIntent) {
            showPD(bufferIntent);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // Unregister broadcast receiver
    try{    if (mBroadcastIsRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastBufferReceiver);
            mBroadcastIsRegistered = false;
        }}catch (Exception e){}
        super.onPause();
    }

    // -- onResume register broadcast receiver. To improve, retrieve saved
    // screen data ---
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // Register broadcast receiver
        if (!mBroadcastIsRegistered) {
            registerReceiver(broadcastBufferReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    Music_service.BROADCAST_BUFFER));
            mBroadcastIsRegistered = true;
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

the logcat

```
10-11 01:52:18.734: W/System.err(561):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:294)
10-11 01:52:18.734: W/System.err(561):  at source.justanothermusicplayer.NowPlaying$3.onSwipeLeft(NowPlaying.java:88)
10-11 01:52:18.744: W/System.err(561):  at source.justanothermusicplayer.classes.OnSwipeTouchListener$GestureListener.onFling(OnSwipeTouchListener.java:45)
10-11 01:52:18.744: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:579)
10-11 01:52:18.744: W/System.err(561):  at source.justanothermusicplayer.classes.OnSwipeTouchListener.onTouch(OnSwipeTouchListener.java:16)
10-11 01:52:18.744: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5481)
10-11 01:52:18.744: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
10-11 01:52:18.744: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
10-11 01:52:18.754: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
10-11 01:52:18.764: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
10-11 01:52:18.764: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
10-11 01:52:18.764: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
10-11 01:52:18.764: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
10-11 01:52:18.764: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
10-11 01:52:18.774: W/System.err(561):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
10-11 01:52:18.774: W/System.err(561):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
10-11 01:52:18.774: W/System.err(561):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
10-11 01:52:18.784: W/System.err(561):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1840)
10-11 01:52:18.794: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5662)
10-11 01:52:18.794: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2863)
10-11 01:52:18.794: W/System.err(561):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
10-11 01:52:18.814: W/System.err(561):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-11 01:52:18.814: W/System.err(561):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-11 01:52:18.824: W/System.err(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-11 01:52:18.824: W/System.err(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 01:52:18.824: W/System.err(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-11 01:52:18.834: W/System.err(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-11 01:52:18.834: W/System.err(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-11 01:52:18.834: W/System.err(561):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Next time,when u downvote,give valid reasons

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, but you could try opening you intents like this instead.-

```
intentswap = new Intent(YourActivityClass.this, ActivityToOpen.class);
intentswap.putExtra("swap",1 );
openIntent(intentswap);
```

Comment: i am sorry i didn't write the full code before,now i have updated the question.

Comment: I have seen your updated answer.
If that was the case,then other intents would have also failed....like 
 intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_SEEKBAR);

but this is working fine......and also this is a broadcast...and simple broadcast are not meant for single activity to fetch,any activity which has a broadcast receiver registered can fetch it.The way you have initialized makes it specific to a single activity and hence it doesn't remain a broadcast anymore..

Comment: Mmh yeah you're right. Does onSwipeRight is working? Could you update the question with the complete stacktrace?

Comment: nope Swipe Right isn't working as well and this is the complete logcat...These swipes were working fine when i was not controlling the musicplayer(inside service) with another activity.

Note:I am trying to create a music player.at first i was doing it without a service,but then it would not have played in background for a long time.(Swipes were working fine till then)So i setted up a service and i am trying to control them via an activity.I am able to control the Seekbar but not these swipe gestures..